# Access Aerospike cluster in Kubernetes via port forwarding?

Tags: aerospike

I have an aerospike cluster running on Kubernetes. I can port forward port 3000 on the main connection point, and can connect to that, but that will return other network addresses of other parts of the aerospike cluster to the client that the client outside of Kubernetes can't access.

Are there any solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are a few approaches to connecting to the Aerospike cluster from clients outside of Kubernetes. They are documented at [Expose Aerospike StatefulSet in Kubernetes](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/deploy_guides/kubernetes/expose/)